# VMware Workstation pro 12.5.9 Copy and paste not working

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, cut-and-paste

Im having problems getting the copy and paste functionality working using VMware Workstation pro 12.5.9. The host and guest are both Win 10 x64. VMtools are installed too.

Ive tried the following but still no luck:

- Host / Guest UAC disabled
- tried disabling and enabling guest isolation copy/paste with a reboot for guest and host
- rdpclip kill and execution attempted on host / guest , ie
  Taskkill.exe /im rdpclip.exe
  rdpclip.exe
- echo off | clip
- disabling Norton (NIS) on host and guest with reboot

Does anybody have any suggestions that i could try?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just tried an archieved xp VM machine that i had. This without doing anything copy and past worked between Win 10 Host and XP Guest. HW compatibility = v8. Seems like the problem is with the Win 10 Guest. The investigation continues....

Comment: solved. Rolled guest Win 10 image to fresh install. Updated HW comp to v12. Installed VM tool again. Initially copy paste didnt work but suspended the VM and Powered it back up and Copy paste worked :)

Comment: Write this up as the Answer and mark is as such. This will help other people who have the same problem who find your question here.